How to get symbolicated crash reports for Microsoft Store app built with Qt
I have a Qt app that I publish via the Microsoft Store. Within the Microsoft Partner Centre, the Insights > Health page shows crash/hang reports. Whenever these occur, they are indicated on the top Failure Hits graph (last 72 hours or last 1 month). However, in the more detailed Failures panel lower down, they are always listed as "Unknown".
Here's what I have done to try and get symbolicated crash/hang reports:

Build my Qt 6 (CMake) app on Windows using the Qt 6.5.5 MSVC2019 64bit kit.
Build it in Release with Debug Information mode to generate the .pdb file. (I can see the generated file in the build folder.)
Use the CMake code below to package, bundle & sign the app and generate a .appxupload file that contains the bundle and the symbols. (Then I build the app and call cmake --install ..)
Create a Package Flight on Microsoft Partner Centre > Apps & Games > My app and upload the .appxupload file. This works fine and I can install the package via the Microsoft Store app.
Within my latest package I have intentionally created easter eggs to let me generate hangs and crashes. These show up within Microsoft Partner Centre > Insights > Health but marked "Unknown" so that I cannot get additional detail.

CMake code for packaging etc.
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install")
set(APP_TARGET "my-app-target")

set(package_x64_command "MakeAppx.exe pack /d \"${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}\" /p \"${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/packages/${APP_TARGET}_x64.appx\"")
set(package_x64_execute_process "execute_process(COMMAND ${package_x64_command})")

set(bundle_command "MakeAppx.exe bundle /d \"${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/packages\" /p \"${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${APP_TARGET}.appxbundle\"")
set(bundle_execute_process "execute_process(COMMAND ${bundle_command})")

set(sign_command "SignTool.exe sign /v /fd SHA256 /sha1 \"${MY_PFX_THUMBPRINT}\" /f \"${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${MY_PFX_SIGNATURE_KEY}\" /p \"${MY_PFX_PASSWORD}\" \"${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${APP_TARGET}.appxbundle\"")
set(sign_execute_process "execute_process(COMMAND ${sign_command})")

set(compress_pdb_command "powershell.exe -Command \"Compress-Archive -Path '${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${APP_TARGET}.pdb' -DestinationPath '${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${APP_TARGET}.appxsym.zip'\"")
set(compress_pdb_execute_process "execute_process(COMMAND ${compress_pdb_command})")

set(rename_appxsym_command "powershell.exe -Command \"Rename-Item -Path '${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${APP_TARGET}.appxsym.zip' -NewName '${APP_TARGET}.appxsym'\"")
set(rename_appxsym_execute_process "execute_process(COMMAND ${rename_appxsym_command})")

set(create_appxupload_command "powershell.exe -Command \"Compress-Archive -Path '${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${APP_TARGET}.appxbundle', '${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${APP_TARGET}.appxsym' -DestinationPath '${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${APP_TARGET}.appxupload.zip'\"")
set(create_appxupload_execute_process "execute_process(COMMAND ${create_appxupload_command})")

set(rename_appxupload_command "powershell.exe -Command \"Rename-Item -Path '${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${APP_TARGET}.appxupload.zip' -NewName '${APP_TARGET}.appxupload'\"")
set(rename_appxupload_execute_process "execute_process(COMMAND ${rename_appxupload_command})")

install(CODE "
    message(\"Removing previous packages and bundle (if present)\")
    file(REMOVE_RECURSE \"${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/packages\")
    file(REMOVE \"${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${APP_TARGET}.appxbundle\")
    file(REMOVE \"${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${APP_TARGET}.appxsym\")
    file(REMOVE \"${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${APP_TARGET}.appxupload\")
    message(\"Packaging 64-bit app\")
    ${package_x64_execute_process}
    message(\"Bundling all packages\")
    ${bundle_execute_process}
    message(\"Signing bundle\")
    ${sign_execute_process}
    message(\"Converting .pdb to .appxsym\")
    ${compress_pdb_execute_process}
    ${rename_appxsym_execute_process}
    message(\"Creating .appxupload file\")
    ${create_appxupload_execute_process}
    ${rename_appxupload_execute_process}
    message(\"done\")
    ")

